# Generator function: Too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: python, numpy, conv-neural-network, autoencoder

I have created a custom generator that yields a tuple of `corrupted_image` and `original_image`.

If I call this generator like this:

```
(corrupted_images_batch, orig_images_batch) = next(test_generator)
```

It returns the expected output i.e 64 images in both the batches. For training my model I need to iterate over the entire batch.

But if I try doing something like:

```
for (corrupted_images_batch, orig_images_batch) in next(test_generator):
    print(corrupted_images_batch)
```

I get an error: `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`.

Comment: Try `for (..., ....) in test_generator:` without the next.

Comment: You define a `custom_image_generator()` function but your examples all refer to `test_generator` which is unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As demonstrated by `(corrupted_images_batch, orig_images_batch) = next(test_generator)`, `next(test_generator)` is a 2-tuple, so you can't loop over it unpacking each element into a 2-tuple.

What you're looking for is:

```py
for (corrupted_images_batch, orig_images_batch) in test_generator:
    print(corrupted_images_batch)
```

This way you're looping over the generator, not just the next element generated.